# Android (setRepeatingAlarm () ) repeating alarm in custom days interval

Tags: android, alarmmanager

[// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

how would i schedule the alarm on a custom date. For example every Monday, Tuesday and Friday?
Do i create multiple instance of Alarm Manager?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting a repeating alarm set a series of exact alarms. So set an alarm for Monday then when that goes off set the next one for 24hrs later (Tuesday) then when that goes off set the next one for Friday.